# another phrase for 'far from business and politics'

Tags: phrase-requests, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Is there any idiomatic expression to convey the meaning such as 'far from a specific topic or an area of activities' in English?

> These survey conclusions summarize opinions of ordinary users that are far away from business and politics.

I want to find a correct phrase because  what I've come up with sounds weird in my opinion.

Comment: What's "far way"? The *ordinary users*, or their *opinions*?

Comment: And what is a "user"? What are they using? Drugs? Software? Soap?

Comment: @ FumbleFingers ordinary users are not involved in business and politics. They are not interested in such things.

Comment: @  TRomano hypothetical consumers. It is not important what they purchase. They purchase everything you can imagine in your mind. :)

Comment: Probably 'layman' may represent the idea you want to express: 
:  a person who does not belong to a particular profession or who is not expert in some field.

Comment: @ Josh61, ok I will go with a 'layman'. But what does the whole phrase sound like?

Comment: These survey conclusions summarize opinions of ordinary users who are far removed from business and politics.                        These survey conclusions summarize opinions of ordinary users who are unassociated with business and politics.

Comment: Please suggest whether I can use 'far away from business' here. Does it sound ok to you?

Comment: I would go with [far removed](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/be-far-removed-from-sth), kudos to Joe Dark. It seems idiomatic.

Comment: @  CopperKettle thanks. Let's wait for native English speakers.

Comment: If they are potential consumers, I'd call them consumers, not "users", and would say Joe Dark's first suggestion, *far removed from*, is better than *unassociated with*, since being associated with an abstraction such as "business" or "politics" doesn't sound quite right to me.

Comment: I thinks any more "off the grid" is what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to indicate a person who is not especially attuned to business or politics. One is to say that person's interests lie elsewhere, which in your example might read as follows:

> These survey conclusions summarize opinions of ordinary users whose principal interests lie outside business and politics.

Answer (score 0):

> These survey conclusions summarize opinions of ordinary users that are far away from business and politics.

You could also use:

> These survey conclusions summarize opinions of ordinary users, those **not engaged** in business and politics.

In the stead of *not engaged*, Joe Dark's *[far removed (from)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/be-far-removed-from-sth)* would also fit nicely.